# SurfaceView strange behavior Android Out of Memory Error

Tags: android, out-of-memory, surfaceview

I am doing what http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-ii,772.html has done but I am making new instances of SurfaceView that are causing Out of memory exception.

I have done profiling with the help of Eclipse MAT and it showed me that SurfaceView has never died. although I am killing the thread that is running onDraw and also the activity but still it remains present in memory.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably remove SurfaceViews that you aren't using from the view hierarchy by calling `ViewGroup#removeView(surfaceView)` on their parents. The `SurfaceView`, and objects in general, can't be garbage collected until no other objects are referencing them.

You might also consider reusing SurfaceViews instead of creating new ones.

Comment: I have removed all views and call backs by calling RelativeLayout animationPanel = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.AnimationPanel));
  animationPanel.clearChildFocus(p); //p is Panel ref
  animationPanel.clearDisappearingChildren();
  animationPanel.clearFocus();
  
  animationPanel.removeAllViews();
  animationPanel.removeAllViewsInLayout();
  animationPanel.removeCallbacks(ViewThread.currentThread());

Comment: but still when analyse it with Eclipse MAT it shows me that ref of layout is due to ViewThread.

Comment: hmm, is there anyway you can reuse the views instead? There isn't much point to having multiple ones in an Activity anyway.

Comment: actually I am making a game in which users can view different tanks and every tank logic is different, so I have to use different panel. android-sdk-windows\samples\android-9\LunarLander My logic is 100% same as Google provided in sample code but I have more than one SurfaceViews and they are not getting removed, although I am canceling callBacks of the thread but still problem.

Comment: You should be able to do that without changing the surface view... It is like a big canvas where you can draw a multitude of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with SurfaceViews. I added a `View` and removed it, but it the Garbage Collector did not destroy it.

The problem was that I overwrote the method `onDetachedFromWindow` in `SurfaceView` and did not call `super.onDetachedFromWindow()`. This way the `SurfaceView` registered a CallBack and did not unregister it.